# Mat-select won't reset from sibling component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular13

When I click the button in the component (child-two) where the mat-select is placed, then the reset works but if I click the reset button in the sibling component (child-one) it doesn't work. How can I accomplish that?

**Parent Component HTML**

```
 <div class="styling">
    <child-one
       (reset)="reset($event)">
    </child-one>
 </div>
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="'over'" class="sidenav">
    <child-two
       class="content-style">
    </child-two>
 </mat-sidenav>
```

**Parent Component TS**

```
  @ViewChild(ChildOne) childOneComponent;
  @ViewChild(ChildTwo) childTwoComponent;

  reset($event: boolean) {
     if ($event) {
         this.childTwoComponent.resetMatSelect();
     }
  }
```

**ChildTwo Component HTML**

```
   <mat-form-field *ngIf="list && list.length > 0" appearance="legacy">
        <mat-label>Cities</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
                    (selectionChange)="emit($event.value)">
            <mat-option [value]="null" i18n>City</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let city of list"
                        [value]="city">
                {{city?.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="resetMatSelect()">reset</button>
```

**ChildTwo Component TS**

```
  resetMatSelect() {
     this.selectedCity = null; 
  }
```

**ChildOne Component HTML**

```
<button mat-stroked-button  *ngIf="showResetButton()" (click)="resetFilters()">
    <mat-icon>restart_alt</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**ChildOne Component TS**

```
resetFilters() {
    this.filters.cities = null;
    this.reset.emit(true);
}
```

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce your issue, see this StackBlitz for reference:: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8amut6?file=.stackblitzrc

Comment: @PhilippKief issue solved - see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved and it has a completely different reason, but I think that the post can save one or the other time if I explain it. Explanation:

The bindings between the parent and child components work as they should. But be careful while using two (or multiple) times the same child component in the parent component.

In the parent component, I have the childTwo-component at two places

```
 <div class="styling">
    <child-one
       (reset)="reset($event)">
    </child-one>
 </div>
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="'over'" class="sidenav">
    <child-two
       class="content-style-port">
    </child-two>
 </mat-sidenav>
       .
       . (more code)
       . 
   <child-two
     class="content-style">
   </child-two>
```

The reason why I have used it in two places was, that the component has to be responsive and at a specific width and it should disappear and 'move' into the sidenav. So each time the reset button clicked, the reset was executed in the component that was not visible.

Problem solved as follows:

**HTML**

```
<child-two *ngIf="!enableSidenavFilter"
     class="content-style">
</child-two>
```

**TS**

```
 enableSidenavFilter = false;

 @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
 onResize(event) {
    this.enableSidenavFilter = window.innerWidth < 1000;
 }
```